# How to cast a numeric column to string within Pyspark ML Pipeline?

Tags: pyspark, pipeline

Let's say I have a simple pipeline like this:

```
feature_columns = ["x1", "x2"]
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=feature_columns, outputCol="features")
rf = RandomForestClassifier(labelCol="label", featuresCol="features")
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[assembler, rf])
```

It has two input features `x1` and `x2` and a target column named `label`.

I want add a typecast step to convert a type of x1 from `int` to `double`. I could have typecasted it explicitly before feeding to the model but I want to have the cast step as a part of the pipeline itself.

How can I do that? One option would be to use a custom transformer that would do the casting but I wish to know if there is anything already available to do so.

Comment: Why do you want to add the data casting in the ML pipeline but not doing it with SQL before your dataframe pass the pipeline?

Comment: It's in a production system where the data is already being SAVED AND USED like that. Also, converting this datatype in inference service creates unnecessary complications which could be avoided if it was a part of the pipeline itself.